# How to integrate payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, ccavenue

I implemented a ccavenue payment gateway. When I send a request to ccavenue, it shows an error. The error is:Error Code: 10002     Merchant Authentication failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in php.
Search for the ccavRequestHandler.php file in the integration kit,open it in a editor, you will find some variables declared as $merchant_data,$working_key and $access_code.
Assign the api values which you will from your ccavenue profile to these variable.

p.s. - if you dont have the whole integration kit download the whole integration kit from the ccavenue site

Answer (score 0):

It means you have mentioned wrong merchant ID or haven't  mentioned merchant ID.
If you are sending merchant ID from form then don't mention in ccavRequestHandler.php
If you are testing ccavenue payment gateway then you should use action link in form `https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction` 
and for actual payment `https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction`

```
For more details you can ask for help from ccavenue on service@ccavenue.com  this email
```